# How to programmatically assign class/struct attributes?

Tags: c++, attributes

I am attempting to translate my Python program to C++, but because I am new to C++ I am encountering some problems. The input file is first parsed (works, not shown) to create the `INITIAL_VALUES` dict/map, which I then want to use to assign the `Parameters` class/struct attributes using the `DEST_DICT_PARAMS` dict/map.

I was able to achieve this in Python code with:

```
import dataclasses

INITIAL_VALUES = {
    "BULK": {
        "MAGMA": {
            "M0":    1.0,
            "T0": 1320.0,
        },
        "ASSIM": {
            "M0":    0.0,
            "T0":  600.0,
        },
    }
}
DEST_DICT_PARAMS = {
    'M0': {"MAGMA": 'Mm0', "ASSIM": 'Ma0'},
    'T0': {"MAGMA": 'Tm0', "ASSIM": 'Ta0'},
}

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Parameters:
    Mm0: float = None
    Ma0: float = None
    Ta0: float = None
    Tm0: float = None


class ParametersReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = Parameters()
        self._assignParameters()

    def _assignParameters(self):
        for param_fam, dest in DEST_DICT_PARAMS.items():
            for component, param in dest.items():
                value = INITIAL_VALUES["BULK"][component][param_fam]
                setattr(self.parameters, param, value)

params = ParametersReader()
print(params.parameters)
```

Output:

> Parameters(Mm0=1.0, Ma0=0.0, Ta0=600.0, Tm0=1320.0)

So I wrote the corresponding C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using std::map;
using std::string;

map<string, map<string, map<string, float> > > INITIAL_VALUES = {{
    "BULK", {
        {"MAGMA", {
            {"M0",    1.0},
            {"T0", 1320.0},
        }},
        {"ASSIM", {
            {"M0",    0.0},
            {"T0",  600.0},
        }},
    }
}};

map<string, map<string, string> > DEST_DICT_PARAMS = {{
    {"M0", {{"MAGMA", "Mm0"}, {"ASSIM", "Ma0"}}},
    {"T0", {{"MAGMA", "Tm0"}, {"ASSIM", "Ta0"}}},
}};

struct Parameters {
    float Mm0;
    float Ma0;
    float Ta0;
    float Tm0;
} parameters;

class ParametersReader {
public:
    void assignParameters_() {
        map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator itr0;
        map<string, string>::iterator itr1;

        for (itr0 = DEST_DICT_PARAMS.begin(); itr0 != DEST_DICT_PARAMS.end(); itr0++) {
            for (itr1 = itr0->second.begin(); itr1 != itr0->second.end(); itr1++) {
                parameters.itr1->second = INITIAL_VALUES["BULK"][itr1->first];
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    ParametersReader params;
    params.assignParameters_();
}
```

But I'm getting an error at the line
`parameters.itr1->second = INITIAL_VALUES['BULK'][itr1->first]` saying "no member named 'itr1' in 'Parameters'". That error makes total sense because the code is literally trying to interpret 'itr1' as an attribute name and not the whole 'itr1->second' as the name. I think this comes down to the fact that I can't seem to find a C++ equivalent to Python's `setattr(obj, name, val)` function that takes an object and its attribute name and assigns it a value. Is there a C++ solution to what I am attempting?

Perhaps my entire approach is incompatible with C++. If so, would you kindly suggest an alternative approach? I would like to keep the input file format the same between the Python and C++ versions.

Comment: Python and C++ are pretty different languages.  Instead of trying to convert the python code to C++ code look at what problem the python code solves and then try to solve that problem using the techniques that C++ has.

Comment: In C++ class/struct members must all be defined at compile time in the class declaration and you can't add new ones at runtime.   If one of the members was `std::map<std::string, std::string> attrib;` then you could assign arbitrary "name" = "value" pairs to it but that is just assigning values to an existing member variable not creating new attributes.

Comment: @DaveS, I'm confused (par for the course with me and C++), I thought I already defined the member variables in the struct `Parameters`; and it's only at runtime that I am actually initializing them with a value.

Comment: `parameters` has no member `itr1`. What do you mean when you write `parameters.itr1->second` ?

Comment: I'm saying if you want to add arbitrary "attributes" to an object rather than just setting values for the declared members `float Mm0; float Ma0; float Ta0; float Tm0;` then you need to make up your own scheme using something like `std::map<...>.foo` to support that.  `a.Mm0 = 1.5;` is legal, `a.set("aria-label", "picture of cat");` does not exist as a built-in feature, you must create it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not have runtime reflection like Python.  You cannot look up a class member by name using a runtime string because class member names do not exist at runtime.

What you *can* do is look up a class member via a *pointer to member*.  This is an offset into the object calculated at compile time by the compiler:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, float Parameters::*> > DEST_DICT_PARAMS = {{
    {"M0", {{"MAGMA", &Parameters::Mm0}, {"ASSIM", &Parameters::Ma0}}},
    {"T0", {{"MAGMA", &Parameters::Tm0}, {"ASSIM", &Parameters::Ta0}}},
}};

class ParametersReader {
public:
    void assignParameters_() {
        for (auto& [param_fam, dest] : DEST_DICT_PARAMS) {
            for (auto& [component, param] : dest) {
                parameters.*param = INITIAL_VALUES["BULK"][component][param_fam];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae4f0a416b5285c7)

Note I've also used range-based for loops and structured bindings to clean up your `assignParameters_` function.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no equivalent to Pythons `setattr(self.parameters, param, value)`. If you want to have a mapping between strings and members you need to write it yourself.

You can use pointers to members to do something along the line of:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    float a = 0.0f;
    float b = 0.0f;
};

// list all members and their string represenation
std::map<std::string,float foo::*> mmap {
    { "a", &foo::a },
    { "b", &foo::b }
};


int main() {
    foo f;
    std::map<std::string,float> values {
        {"a", 0.1},
        {"b", 0.2}
    };

    
    for (const auto& val : values) {
        // lookup the member pointers via the strings from mmap
        // use the found function pointer to assing to corresponding member in f
        f.*mmap[val.first] = val.second;
    }

    std::cout << f.a << " " << f.b << "\n";
}
```

Note that the code assumes that all strings present in `values` are also present in `mmap`. If not, it will fail horribly. To fix that `mmap.find` should be used instead and the case of not found string handleted appropriately.

This works, though there is no way to get that mapping implicitly from the class definition only. On the other, hand I can imagine libraries to exist that can help with that.